# Declaring global const objects in a header file

Tags: c++, global-variables, c++14, range-v3

In Eric Niebler's range-v3 library, he provides a lot of headers that each have their own global function object. They are all declared in the same way. He provides a class template [`static_const`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/utility/static_const.hpp):

```
template<typename T>
struct static_const
{
    static constexpr T value {};
};

template<typename T>
constexpr T static_const<T>::value;
```

And then every function object of type `F` is declared as:

```
namespace
{
    constexpr auto&& f = static_const<F>::value;
}
```

What are the advantages of introducing the object through the `static_const` template *and* in an unnamed namespace, as opposed to just writing:

```
static constexpr F f{};
```

Comment: The contexpr is very vital here.. If it would be a simple `const` or a non-const and you were to use such a template, you cannot guarantee initialization one after another, since ordered initialization within a TU is not done for instantiated variables. The `constexpr` guarantees that no dynamic initialization will happen, so this will not be observable here, AFAIK.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Isn't it unordered anyway?

Comment: if that were true, `int x = rand(); int y = x + 1;` at global scope would be undefined behavior :) in general for non-instantiated variables it is ordered.

Comment: Destination of `static_const` described in details in Eric Niebler's [D4381](http://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4381.html) and corresponding [article](http://ericniebler.com/2014/10/21/customization-point-design-in-c11-and-beyond/). Mostly it concerned *one-definition-rule* and preventing of its violation.

Comment: This is basically poor man's inline variables.

Comment: @T.C. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @Barry See [N4424](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4424.pdf), a proposal introduce inline variables mostly to solve ODR problems.

Comment: @Orient, that should be an answer (as it's the right one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is basically the one definition rule.

If you just have:

```
static constexpr F f{};
```

The name `f` has internal linkage, which means that every translation unit has its own `f`. The consequence of that means that, for instance, an inline function which takes the address of `f` would get a different address based on which translation unit the call occurred in:

```
inline auto address() { return &f; } // which f??
```

Which means now we might actually have multiple definitions of `address`. Really, any operation that takes the address of `f` is suspect.

From [D4381](http://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4381.html#no-violations-of-the-one-definition-rule):

> ```
> // <iterator>
> namespace std {
>   // ... define __detail::__begin_fn as before...
>   constexpr __detail::_begin_fn {};
> }
>
> // header.h
> #include <iterator>
> template <class RangeLike>
> void foo( RangeLike & rng ) {
>   auto * pbegin = &std::begin; // ODR violation here
>   auto it = (*pbegin)(rng);
> }
>
> // file1.cpp
> #include "header.h"
> void fun() {
>   int rgi[] = {1,2,3,4};
>   foo(rgi); // INSTANTIATION 1
> }
>
> // file2.cpp
> #include "header.h"
> int main() {
>   int rgi[] = {1,2,3,4};
>   foo(rgi); // INSTANTIATION 2
> }
> ```
>
> The code above demonstrates the potential for ODR violations if the global `std::begin` function object is defined naïvely. Both functions fun in file1.cpp and main in file2.cpp cause the implicit instantiation `foo<int[4]>`. Since global const objects have internal linkage, both translation units file1.cpp and file2.cpp see separate `std::begin` objects, and the two foo instantiations will see different addresses for the `std::begin` object. That is an ODR violation.

---

On the other hand, with:

```
namespace
{
    constexpr auto&& f = static_const<F>::value;
}
```

while `f` still has internal linkage, `static_const<F>::value` has *external* linkage due to its being a static data member. When we take the address of `f`, it being a reference means that we're actually taking the address of `static_const<F>::value`, which only has one unique address across the whole program.

An alternative is to use variable templates, which are required to have external linkage - which requires C++14, and is also demonstrated in that same link:

> ```
> namespace std {
>   template <class T>
>   constexpr T __static_const{};
>   namespace {
>     constexpr auto const& begin =
>       __static_const<__detail::__begin_fn>;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Because of the external linkage of variable templates, every translation unit will see the same address for `__static_const<__detail::__begin_fn>`. Since `std::begin` is a reference to the variable template, it too will have the same address in all translation units.
>
> The anonymous namespace is needed to keep the `std::begin` reference itself from being multiply defined. So the reference has internal linkage, but the references all refer to the same object. Since every mention of `std::begin` in all translation units refer to the same entity, there is no ODR violation ([[basic.def.odr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.def.odr#6)).

---

In C++17, we won't have to worry about this at all with the new inline variable feature, and just write:

```
inline constexpr F f{};
```